# Is there a way to get Windows to ignore the manual WindowStartupLocation I'm using for a particular window?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, window-handles

I'm using [WindowStartupLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation?view=netcore-3.1).Manual to open a window on my app and I wonder if there is a way to tell Windows to ignore that location and do not open the next window after this one (where it is not mentioned a specific location for it) following my window's location..

*"Setting the WindowStartupLocation property to Manual causes a window to be positioned according to its Left and Top property values. If either the Left or Top properties aren't specified, their values are determined by Windows."*

Comment: Why just not open the window? Putting an if condition before the show line, for example.

Comment: The thing is, I'm adding a new window to a legacy application.. I open it on a very specific location.. but after that, some of the other windows of that same application are opened at a location based on the location I gave to the new window.. I guess that it is due to the fact that some of the other windows does not have a specify location assigned to them..

Comment: The CreateWindowEx() call allows an app to specify a default location (CW_USEDEFAULT).  The OS then opens the window staggered towards the right/bottom from the previous window.  If you don't control that call then there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I could not reproduce the issue. A little research led me to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.windowstartuplocation?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#fields).
There are other two factors that affect the positioning of the window.

1. `CenterOwner`: The startup location of a Window is the center of the Window that owns it, as specified by the `Owner` property.
2. `CenterScreen`: The startup location of a Window is the center of the screen that contains the mouse cursor.

So you can check the `Owner` property or check the mouse position when testing.

You can set the Owner window as follows:

```
Window1 p =new Window1();
p.Owner = this;
```